# How to segue with sender as MKAnnotation

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to segue from a right control button in a map annotation:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTramsView", sender: view)
        }
    }
```

But I need the sender as an MKAnnotation as that has details I need to send to the target VC. Right now the sender is the pin. How can I do this?

Comment: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTramsView", sender: view.annotation)`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez answer should be the accepted one